# Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I need help with this macro.  Every time I run it, I get the error below.  I thought it was a simple macro that I could have anybody on my team use to make it take a less time than they were taking to manually create this PivotTable every time they ran the report.  However, it's not working.  Please see error below and advise.  I emboldened and italicized the error.

[image: Error]

```
Sub LEDOTTR()
'
' LEDOTTR Macro
'

'
    Range("A87").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    ***ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet1!R87C1:R8214C25", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="LED OTTR!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable6", _
        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14***
    Sheets("LED OTTR").Select
    Cells(1, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("LED")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("Hierarchy name")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("LED").CurrentPage = "(All)"
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("LED")
        .PivotItems("LED Marine").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("LL48 Linear LED").Visible = False
        .PivotItems("Other").Visible = False
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").PivotFields("LED"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable6").PivotFields("   Late " & Chr(10) & "Indicator"), "Sum of    Late " & Chr(10) & "Indicator", _
        xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable6").PivotFields("Early /Ontime" & Chr(10) & "   Indicator"), _
        "Sum of Early /Ontime" & Chr(10) & "   Indicator", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like you might have an issue supplying a name to the table that is a fixed value.  You are calling it `PivotTable6` but that name is only available the first time you create the pivot.  After that, you will have a clash.

Answer (score 10):

The answer to your problem is [located here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/604666-visual-basic-applications-pivot-table-error-5-0_o.html#post2998219).

Your sheet name in `TableDestination:="LED OTTR!R1C1"` **needs to be surrounded with single quotes** in order for it to work `TableDestination:="'LED OTTR'!R1C1"`

You will also have problems with the duplicated name if you do not delete this PivotTable before rerunning the code.

Comment: A quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+pivot+table+error+5) would have found the answer as well.  That link is the first result.  Oddly enough they go through the same progression as me looking at the duplicated name.  For reference, the duplicated name gives a 1004 error.

Comment: @user3067028, good to hear.  Please mark as the answer (check under vote buttons) so that others will know its resolved.  Helps all of us.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the trouble was related to the region settings in Windows. I downloaded a (protected) xlsm file from the internet and always got the "Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument" error when opening it. The other answer hinted to me that it may have to do with the language settings. The scripts in the file were obviously programmed in German while my Windows was set to an English region.

In Windows 10 `Settings > Time & Language > Region` I changed `Region` as well as `Regional format` to German. After restarting Excel, the file worked.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this, and the error was caused by calling the `Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` method on a hidden worksheet.

I just added the `if worksheet.Visible Then` condition to my code to prevent getting the `Invalid Procedure Call or Argument` error.

Answer (score 0):

While installing macro file to excel 2016 ribbon window getting below error when I debug the error. Below section was highlighed in yellow collor when clicked on debug

Set one = Application.CommandBars("Worksheet Menu Bar").Controls.Add(Type:= _
msoControlPopup, before:=onecount)

Comment: Just to add for more info ... this same macro file would work on Office 2010 fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).