# Excel VBA Pivot Cache Type Mismatch Run-Time Error '13'

Tags: excel, runtime-error, pivot-table, vba

Thanks for any input on this. I'm trying to make a simple pivot table that is taking data from sheet "5 Month Trending May 15" and putting it onto my Pivot Table sheet called "Errors By Criticality - Pivot".

When I try to set the pivot cache range with the create method it's returning a runtime error of type mismatch. I've checked the parameters and it looks like I'm setting it up correctly. I did try to specify the PivotTable version and was still getting the same error. My code is below.

I'm assuming it's something to do with the pvtCache variable or the way I'm setting it to the range but I can't figure any solutions out.

```
Sub PivotTableCode()

Dim pvtCache As PivotCache 
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem 
'Set the cache of the pivot table
Sheets("5 Month Trending May 15").Select
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, Range("A2:H38"))

'create the Pivot Table
Sheets("Errors by Criticality - Pivot").Select
Set pvt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(pvtCache, Range("AP2"), "MyPivotTable") 
End Sub
```

Comment: Where does this code reside?  Inside a `Worksheet` or `ThisWorkbook` or a Module?  An unqualified call to `Range` behaves differently depending on where the code executes (main issue is inside a `Worksheet`).  You can test that issue by using  `Application.Range` instead of `Range`.  Also, can you create the Pivot Table manually?  That is no issues with bad header names, blank headers, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the response Byron! The code I have above is inside a module. I input the code into the `"5 Month Trending"` space for code and I'm still getting the same error. I can make the Pivot Table manually no problem myself. It's just not setting the cache correctly for some reason.

Comment: Try giving the `Range("A2:H38")` as a `String` with the full Range and Sheet name: `"'Sheet Name'!A2:H38"'.  Pivot Cache is supposed to be able to take a `Range` there, but maybe there is a disconnect between the `ActiveSheet` and the sheet you expect or some other Range related issue.

Comment: Awesome! Changing it to a `String` as `"'5 Month Trending May 15'!A2:H38"` set the cache correctly. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Just for curiosity, can you also try: `Worksheets("5 Month Trending May 15").Range("A2:H38")`?  If that works, it means that somehow your call to `Range` is not in the proper context which would be odd since you `Select` it immediately above, but who knows.  If it doesn't work, then there is some issue with Range there, which I can't really explain.

Comment: I tried the `Worksheets("5 Month Trending May 15").Range("A2:H38")` before when I was thinking that it wasn't grabbing the range from the correct worksheet and that still gave me a type mismatch. I'm confused on why it did give me that error too, so maybe using `PivotCaches.Create` you have to have the range in a Excel text format? I'm totally guessing though. (Also if you submit your answer I'll mark it as solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for PivotCaches.Create](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839430.aspx) indicates

> The `SourceData` argument is required if `SourceType` isn't `xlExternal`. It can be a `Range` object (when `SourceType` is either `xlConsolidation` or `xlDatabase`) or an Excel Workbook Connection object (when `SourceType` is `xlExternal`).

Despite this, the macro recorder will always create a `String` here for the `SourceData`.  [(It will even create a bad string if the `Sheet` has a space in the name).](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538131/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument/30540014#30540014)

Given the preference for the macro recorder, I often supply this as a `String` with the addresses.

I have been able before to supply a `Range` here so I am not certain what is specifically going on that prevents the `Range` usage in this case.

To use a `String`, your code would look like:

```
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'5 Month Trending May 15'!A2:H38")
```