# VBA PivotTableWizard syntax error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm dealing with a simple *syntax* error, in this line of code...

```
Set PvtTbl = wsPvtTbl.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, 
    SourceData:=rngData, TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("A1"),
    TableName:="PivotTable1")
```

If anybody can spot the problem here, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: what is the error which you are getting

Comment: The error has switched from "syntax error" to a Run-time error '1004': The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns. If you are changingthe name of a PivotTable field, you must type a new name for the field.

Comment: Might be related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30807519/4288101.  The solution there was to provide the `SourceData` as a `String` instead of a `Range`.