# Creating a Pivot Table with Excel VBA in Excel 2016 - Run-Time error 1004

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

UPDATES:

I'm currently trying to create a temporary table with Excel VBA in Excel 2016. I've got my variables set up, but unfortunately, I keep running into errors when I try to run the code below.

I've tried running multiple variations of the code below, but to no avail. I've tried running with variables as strings, ranges, variants, and I still run into an error 1004: application-defined or object-defined issue.

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim dateSel As Variant
    Dim tSheet, sARR As Worksheet
    Dim pTable As PivotTable
    Dim pRange As Range
    Dim lastRow, lastCol As Long

    dateSel = ActiveCell.Value

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets.Add before:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "TempTable"
    Set tSheet = Worksheets("TempTable")
    Set sARR = Worksheets("All_Risk_Report")

    lastRow = sARR.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = sARR.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    Set pRange = sARR.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastRow, lastCol)

    Set pTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=pRange.Address).CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=tSheet.Cells(2, 2))

End Sub
```

I thought this code would work to create a temporary pivot table so I can get some values, paste them, then get rid of the table, but it's hard to do that if the table won't create itself. I had also thought that declaring pRange to reference a specific sheet's data would work as well.

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1. Break the pivot cache creation and the pivot table creation into two lines. 2. Pass the `SourceData` parameter a String - see the [`PivotCaches.Create`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcaches.create) documentation: When passing a Range object, we recommend that you either use a string to specify the workbook, worksheet, and cell range, or set up a named range and pass the name as a string. Passing a Range object may cause "type mismatch" errors unexpectedly.

Comment: Update - I've got a new issue now with the following code:

```
    Set pTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=pRange.Address).CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=tSheet.Cells(2, 2))
```

The error that gets thrown now is Run-time error '1004':

Application defined or object defined error.

I love Excel... but it does not love me back.

Comment: `pRange.Address` - this doesn't include the sheet name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Pivot Cache Type Mismatch Run-Time Error '13'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30785499/excel-vba-pivot-cache-type-mismatch-run-time-error-13)

Comment: Or see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606962/pivotcache-create-unable-to-handle-large-range).

Comment: Thanks for the help, @BigBen. I've just checked that out and figured out a work-around based on your suggestion of passing the source data name as a string. The last bit of code now looks like this:

`    pAddy = sARR.Name & "!" & pRange.address
    
    Set pTable = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:=pAddy).CreatePivotTable( _
                TableDestination:=tSheet.Cells(2, 2))`

That worked perfectly.

Thanks again!

Comment: Just in case someone in the future has this issue - if the sheet name has spaces in it, it should be enclosed within single quotes. Not applicable to you here: (All_Risk_Report).

Comment: Still note - I'd break the pivot cache creation and the pivot table creation into two separate steps.