# Copying 1 file into multiple subdirectories

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have found one code snippet that successfully copies 1 file to one specific directory. However what I am trying to piece together is a way to copy one file into hundreds of subdirectories. I have also found code that recursively cycles through subfolders and allows you to take action upon the files in the subfolders. Surely there must be a mash up of these two codes that would allow me to copy the 1 file into numerous subdirectories.
If this is not possible I have working code for a command prompt.

```
Sub Copy_Certain_Files_In_Folder()
'This example copy all Excel files from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
'existing files in this folder

Dim fso As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Dim FileExt As String

'FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
'ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

FileExt = "*.pdf"  '<< Change
'You can use *.* for all files or *.doc for Word files

If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    FromPath = FromPath & "\"
End If

Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

If fso.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
    MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

If fso.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
    MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
    Exit Sub
End If

fso.CopyFile Source:=FromPath & FileExt, Destination:=ToPath
MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Code that cycles through subfolders:

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

HostFolder = "C:\"

Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
Dim SubFolder
For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
    DoFolder SubFolder
Next
Dim File
For Each File In Folder.Files
    ' Operate on each file
Next
End Sub
```

Any advice is welcome!

Comment: Are you trying to place a copy of this file into all subfolders of the given destination directory? Can you help us understand why you want to make multiple copies of the file?

Comment: Correct. 
Sorry I wasn't clear on that I am trying to copy a file Doug.pdf from the root Billing Folder into a hundred or so company folders that exist in that same directory. 
So in S:\Billing there is Doug.pdf 
and I want to copy Doug.pdf into 
S:\Billing\Company A,  
S:\Billing\Company B,  
S:\Billing\Company C,  
S:\Billing\Company d etc.

Comment: As to the why on earth am I trying to do this with Excel VBA When the following command line does the job:
    `for /D %x in ("S:\Billing folder\*.*") DO COPY "S:\Billing folder\*.pdf" "%x\"`
Is because Excel VBA is basically the only code I can run in the virtual environment I work in. As I said in my original post if trying to get the for loop that seems so simple in the command line is difficult to force VBA to do I will just run the command line. I thought it would be nice if I could find a way to do operations like that with VBA for future projects. @SmrtGrunt

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
'*****************************************************
' FUNCTION HEADER: Put_A_File_In_All_Subfolders
'
' Purpose:  Looks for the specified file, and if it exists it
'       puts the file in all subfolders of the target path.
'
' Inputs:
'       blnFirstIteration: True / false for whether this is the first function call
'       strFromPath As String: The path where the file to copy is located.
'       strToPath As String: The path where the destination folder tree exists.
'       strFileToCopy: The filename to copy.
'*****************************************************

Sub Put_A_File_In_All_Subfolders( _
    blnFirstIteration As Boolean, _
    strFromPath As String, _
    strToPath As String, _
    strFileToCopy As String)

Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject

Dim blnEverythingIsValid As Boolean
blnEverythingIsValid = True

'If this is the first run, check to make sure the initial file
'exists at that path, else throw error messages:
If blnFirstIteration Then
    If Right(strFromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFromPath = strFromPath & "\"
    End If

    If fso.FolderExists(strFromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox strFromPath & " doesn't exist"
        blnEverythingIsValid = False
    Else
        If Not fso.FileExists(strFromPath & strFileToCopy) Then
            MsgBox strFileToCopy & " doesn't exist in " & strFromPath
            blnEverythingIsValid = False
        End If
    End If

    If fso.FolderExists(strToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox strToPath & " doesn't exist"
        blnEverythingIsValid = False
    End If
End If

If blnEverythingIsValid Then
    If Right(strToPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        strToPath = strToPath & "\"
    End If

    'Copy the file to the destination folder
    fso.CopyFile (strFromPath & strFileToCopy), strToPath, True

    'Run the sub recursively for each subfolder
    Dim vntSubFolder As Variant
    Dim currentFolder As Scripting.Folder
    Set currentFolder = fso.GetFolder(strToPath)

    'Check to see if there are subfolders
    If currentFolder.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each vntSubFolder In currentFolder.SubFolders
            'Dim fsoSubFolder As Scripting.Folder
            'Set fsoSubFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.item(vntSubFolder)

            Dim strSubFolderPath As String
            strSubFolderPath = vntSubFolder.Path

            Put_A_File_In_All_Subfolders False, strFromPath, strSubFolderPath, strFileToCopy
        Next vntSubFolder
    End If
Else
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Sub
End If

Set fso = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can call it using:

```
Put_A_File_In_All_Subfolders True, "C:\PathWithFile\", "C:\RootDestinationFolder", "Filename.ext"
```

I mashed that up quickly, so please test before using widely...

Comment: @SmartGrunt
Wow thank you for an amazingly quick solution I have a test area to test in, I will test it thoroughly and make sure it works!

Comment: @SmartGrunt
I am getting a compile error that: 
`Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject `
is a User-Defined Type that is not defined.
Then the VBA debugger highlights the 
Sub Put_A_File_In_All_Subfolders list of arguments as if initializing fso as Scripting.FileSystemObject needed to be included in the arguments of the Sub. I am not certain how to remedy this compile error.
I am also not sure what I just wrote makes enough sense LOL bear with me new here to stackoverflow as a question poster. I have used this resource countless times in my coding adventures.

Comment: @drautio72 - In your VBA editor, go to Tools --> References --> Make sure "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" library is enabled. That should fix it.

Comment: You might also need "System" enabled. I don't remember which library it's in.

Comment: @SmartGrunt
Well super close now! But I am getting Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument when it gets down to:
`Set fsoSubFolder = currentFolder.SubFolders.Item(intSubFolder)`
Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response... I haven't seen that error, but it probably has to do with spaces in the directory names: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538131/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument