# VBA Excel - invalid procedure call or argument when saving the file

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning,

I am facing the following issue.
When I try to save my file under the new version, then I am getting the error from time to time, which states about:
**Invalid procedure call or argument - sChangeVersiojn**
[image]

See my code below:

```
 Sub Version_save()
 ' Saving file under the newer version wothout changing its name
 On Error GoTo E_Handle
 Dim strFileName  As String
 Dim strFileExt As String
 strFileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
 strFileExt = Mid(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, "."))
 strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".") - 1) '   get rid of the file extension (it should be .xlsm)
 strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, "V") - 1) '   now go back to the last "V" in the file name
 strFileName = strFileName & "V" & ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Frontsheet").Range("D38") & ".0" & strFileExt
 ThisWorkbook.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName
 Debug.Print strFileName
 Debug.Print strFileExt
 sExit:
     On Error Resume Next
     Exit Sub
 E_Handle:
     MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sChangeVersiojn", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & 
     Err.Number
     Resume sExit
 End Sub
```

According to thread below:

[Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538131/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument)

I should change the quotes, but I don't really know where should I do it.

Is there any way to get rid of this error?

Comment: Remove the Error-Handle an see where the error occures.

Comment: Use `On Error GoTo 0` so you can at least determine the line that breaks the code

Comment: 'This `strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, ".") - 1)` Or this `strFileName = Left(strFileName, InStrRev(strFileName, "V") - 1)` could be the cause, when the filename doesn't contain an "." or "V"

Comment: Yes you are right. It might be a case. Is there any way to get it over? The problem is, that some of my works contain both "." and "V" and some don't. I need some IF statement or case for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code assumes your file name matches a certain pattern, then goes on to provide an unhelpful error message if it does not.

You could test the file name matches a pattern, then take appropriate action if it does not.  If it does, continue and do the name change and SaveAs.

Add this to the top of your Sub, and change the pattern to suit your needs.

```
'Test if file name contains a "V", and not as first or last character in the name.  Also require a .xlsm or .xlsx extension
If Not ThisWorkbook.Name Like "*?V?*.xls[mx]" Then
    MsgBox "File Name """ & ThisWorkbook.Name & """ does not match required pattern", vbOKOnly, "Error"
    ' File name does not conform.  Now What?
    GoTo sExit
End If
```

Comment: Great! Thanks.
I have switched off GoTo Exit and replaced it with Save As application dialog 
https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/how-to-open-the-save-as-dialog-box-with-vba.535724/
Now the solution works perfect for me! If the pattern dosn't match to the code, I can manually save it straight away!