# Excel VBA ADODB - How to populate data based on an excel column values directly from SQL database without copying data into excel sheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, adodb

I'm running the following code for appending the data into columns B to G. My data is in Snowflake datawarehouse. The data is in millions so I cannot copy it into excel sheet first.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

Dim rs as ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn as ADODB.Connection
Dim connstr as String
Dim sqlstr as String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = DSNdetails.connstr 
'DSNdetails is a module that holds DSN, DBCName, Databasename,Uid and password

cn.Open connstr
cn.Execute "USE WAREHOUSE db_warehouse;"

sqlstr = "SELECT employee_num, name, address, email, phone_num FROM Company;"

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adStateOpen, adLockReadOnly

Sheet1.Cells(2,1).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code runs perfectly. However the issue starts when I add WHERE clause and IN operator.

```
A             |   B  |  C      |  D |

Employee_num  | name | address | phone

123
234
456

and so on
```

So now my new query is as below and Table1 is column A (I have considered it as string as well but same error) User can enter employee_num in each row and no matter how many rows they enter the data should populate in columns B to G if that employee_num in column A exists in SQL/Snowflake database

```
sqlstr = "SELECT employee_num, name, address, phone_num FROM Company WHERE employee_num IN ('"& _
Join(Application.Transpose(Range("Table1[Employee_num]").Value),'",")&");"
```

the code when debugged shows points at

```
rs.Open sqlstr, cn, adStateOpen, adLockReadOnly
```

Edit: Now I have a new runtime error "ODBC driver does not support the requested properties"

Comment: Why write all this text and not actually post the error?

Comment: Just edited. It is a runtime 5 error

Comment: and still... you didn't post the error. I googled runtime 5. Is the error actually "Invalid Procedure Call or Argument"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538131/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument

Comment: apologies, yes it is.

Comment: OK. It's still not edited into the question but whatever. Have you tried extracting the value of the generated SQL query and running it directly?

Comment: Does that `sqlstr = ...` line with the IN clause actually compile?  Seems like there's a single-quote out of place there.  How many rows in the excel listobject?  Is `employee_num` numeric, or text?

Comment: Yes the sqlstr compiles. The employee num is numeric

Comment: I have a new error of "ODBC driver does not support requested properties, which is strange as I did not have this error when I used sqlstr without IN operator.

Comment: I suggest you `debug.print sqlstr` and post the result https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/debug-print-immediate-window

Comment: If the id is numeric then you don't need the single-quotes.