# Issue while trying to convert PHP to VBA

Tags: php, vba

## **I have already checked here: [Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30538131/run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure-call-or-argument)**

## **but this does not work for the below issue**

**About**

> I am trying to convert PHP one line of code into MS Access VBA

**I have following code in PHP**

```
$signKey = hash_hmac('sha256', "20230621", 'AWS41234567', true);
```

I am trying to convert it into VBA MS Access

**Below is the code in VBA**

```
Function CalculateHMAC(ByVal data As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Dim signKey As String
    Dim hmac As Object
    Dim sha256 As Object
    
    Set hmac = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.HMACSHA256")
    hmac.key = StrConv(key, vbFromUnicode)
    
    Set sha256 = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed")
    signKey = hmac.ComputeHash_2(sha256.ComputeHash_2(StrConv(message, vbFromUnicode)))
    
    Set hmac = Nothing
    Set sha256 = Nothing
    CalculateHMAC = signKey
End Function
```

**Testing above function**

```
CalculateHMAC "20230621", "AWS41234567"
```

**Error message while conversion**

> Run Time Error 5 - Invalid Procedure Call or Argument

[image]

Comment: Not sure what `ComputeHash_2()` is, but `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash()` has overloads for taking Streams or Byte[], whereas `StrConv()` returns a `variant`.

Comment: Which line gives the error? (Click on Debug and note which line is highlighted.)